# Could 'Node.JS' sue (and win) a trademark infringement against any software companies that use the word 'Node'?

Tags: trademark

Ever since 'Node.JS' became very popular, a lot of software companies have been using the word 'Node' in their trademarks. For example:

- ControlNode
- NodeStudio
- AppNode

Could Node.JS owners potentially sue (and win) a lawsuit against software companies that have the term 'Node' in them?

Comment: I'd be interested if any of these words are trademarks. IANAL, but my experience of trying to register trademarks indicates that granting authorities are *very* picky about the words they grant, and Node is one that I think they'd fight back against. Especially given how common the word is in prgramming. (I used to work for a company called Mega with a product called Miracle. They tried to TM both names. No go.)

Answer (score 2):

Could they sue?  Yes.  "[Node.js](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=87851829&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch)" is trademarked.

Would they win?  Almost certainly not.  "Node.js" is just one of 424 trademarks registered with the USPTO that contains the word "node", and Joyent, Inc. was granted a very narrow set of goods and services that the trademark applies to, namely "downloadable computer software for use in reading and writing computer code".

Comment: also there's lots of reasons to name your program node based on [what kind of nodes you work with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node#Computing_and_electronics)